# Editing a specific virtual host block using sed

Tags: sed

I have to add a line to a specific virtual host block

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   #
   #Existing Lines
   #

   #--New line should go here
</VirtualHost>
```

The sed script should be such that this line should NOT get added to any other Virtual Host block.

Answer (score 0):

- if awk is accepted check example/test below
- If your file is an xml, i guess there must be an attribute in your  element. e.g `<VirtualHost url="server:port">`
- your xml file should be well-formatted. e.g. it won't be in one single very long line.

if above are satisfied, check the followings:

```
kent$  cat vh.txt 
<VirtualHost url="bar:80">
    <bar>i am virtualHost bar</bar>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost url="here:80">
   #
   #Existing Lines
   #
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost url="foo:80">
    <foo>i am fooo</foo>
</VirtualHost>

kent$  awk '/<VirtualHost url="here:80">/&& !x{x=1;print;next;}/<\/VirtualHost>/&&x==1{$0="NEW_NEW\n"$0;x=2}1' vh.txt
<VirtualHost url="bar:80">
    <bar>i am virtualHost bar</bar>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost url="here:80">
   #
   #Existing Lines
   #
NEW_NEW
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost url="foo:80">
    <foo>i am fooo</foo>
</VirtualHost>
```

the awk onliner above add a new line "NEW_NEW" to the right VirtualHost element.

Comment: the output of your solution has one line missing at line 4

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`. It selects lines between `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `</VirtualHost>`, and in last one inserts the text before it.

```
sed -e '/^<VirtualHost[ ]\*:80>/,/<\/VirtualHost>/ { /<\/VirtualHost>/ i\NEW TEXT' -e '}'
```

An **example**:

Assuming next content for `infile`:

```
<VirtualHost more:80>
   #
   #Existing Lines
   #

   #--New line should go here
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   #
   #Existing Lines
   #

   #--New line should go here
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   #
   #Existing Lines
   #

   #--New line should go here
</VirtualHost>
```

Run it like:

```
sed -e '/^<VirtualHost[ ]\*:80>/,/<\/VirtualHost>/ { /<\/VirtualHost>/ i\NEW TEXT' -e '}' infile
```

With following output:

```
<VirtualHost more:80>
   #
   #Existing Lines
   #

   #--New line should go here
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   #
   #Existing Lines
   #

   #--New line should go here
NEW TEXT
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   #
   #Existing Lines
   #

   #--New line should go here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i get an error which says:
`sed: 1: "/^<VirtualHost[ ]\*:80> ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command`